# Is there a way to set the Width and Height of a UIElement?

Tags: c#, wpf, size, uielement

Is there a way to set the size of a `UIElement` (without casting to `FrameworkElement`), perhaps similar to how using `RenderSize` on a `UIElement` mirrors getting size information via `ActualWidth` & `ActualHeight` on a `FrameworkElement`)?

In effect, I guess you could say I want to **set** the `RenderSize` of a `UIElement`.

I'm thinking along the lines of an approach that would somehow enable me to force a measure / arrange pass with the desired size, but can't seem to find an appropriate point of attack.

Comment: Please tell us what your *actual* or *wider* goal is.

Comment: The actual goal is what the question asks - to be able to be set the Width and Height of a UIElement that is being passed, without casting to anything.

Comment: I was asking *why* you want to do that... maybe there is another way?

Comment: I am passed objects that are only guaranteed to be UIElements. Custom behaviors are attached to them, some of which are resizing behaviors that need to be able to resize their host UIElement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to a way of doing this is to call `Arrange(finalRect)` on the `UIElement`. **If** the element's `ArrangeCore` override (and/or subsequent `OnRender`) implementation "stretches" to / makes use of  the whole area given (by finalRect), its size will be set accordingly. But only if.

Personally, I decided to amputate WPF at its UI neck and build my own layout system and a complete set of UI controls that descend directly from `UIElement`. That way, I sidestep the whole problem, since the granddaddy in my hierarchy, the firstborn son of UIElement, has all the members necessary for layout built in from the getgo - including properties for `Width` and `Height` (and is basically therefore a sizable `UIElement`).

The rest of my code then just deals with grandpa, i.e. my version of "FrameworkElement" (which is way more efficient - since it sheds all the context / dependency / styling functionality etc that I don't need anyway. WPF pays a price for being so generic).

A `FrameworkElementWrapper` control is included in that family, should there be a need to include any conventional `FrameworkElements` in the layout.

Answer (score 2):

This might seem like an easy, or obvious answer, but no, you can't set the `Width` or `Height` of a `UIElement` simply because it does not have those properties. The `UIElement` class is merely a *base class for WPF core level implementations* that provides some basic functionality. From the [`UIElement` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN:

> A UIElement has the following capabilities that are specifically defined by the UIElement class:
>
> • Can render as a child element (UIElement derives from Visual, a high level graphics class)
> • Contains logic that is used to size and position possible child elements of a UIElement (when interpreted by a layout system)
> • Can respond to user input (including control of where input is getting sent to via their handling of event routing, or routing of commands)
> • Can raise routed events that travel a route through the logical element tree
> • Supports some aspects of the animation system

Now when looking at the [`FrameworkElement` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN, we see this:

> FrameworkElement extends UIElement and adds the following capabilities:
>
> • Layout system definition: FrameworkElement provides specific WPF framework-level implementations for certain methods that were defined as virtual members in UIElement. Most notably, FrameworkElement seals certain WPF core-level layout overrides, and instead provides a WPF framework-level equivalent that derived classes should override instead. For example, FrameworkElement seals ArrangeCore but provides ArrangeOverride. These changes reflect the fact that at the WPF framework-level there is a full layout system in place that can render any FrameworkElement derived class. **At the WPF core level, certain members that will structure a general WPF based layout solution are in place, but the actual engine of the layout system is not defined.**

The bold text that I highlighted should further explain why you cannot set the `Width` or `Height` of a `UIElement`.

Comment: The question is not whether I can set the `Width` and `Height` properties on `UIElement`. Since they don't exist, I know that I can't. I am asking if there's a way to _somehow_ set the _size_ of a UIElement (much like you can if you inherit and do a MeasureOverride). If there was something like a public `ForceMeasure(Size size)` method on `UIElement`, for example, this could be done. But there isn't - and I am asking whether there is _some_ way to accomplish the same.

Comment: The answer remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, now we have `SetValue()` for `UIElement`. So it can set some properties indirectly.
E.g. To set Height of a `UIElement` (Without casting it). you can use the following code

```
uIElement.SetValue(Shape.HeightProperty, 300.0);
```

It is a little hard to find all relevant properties to go in the `SetValue()` but is possible.